# Why this "adduser" command give error "The home dir must be an absolute path" in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, odoo

I'm trying to learn Odoo, and as I follow steps from [this site](https://www.candidroot.com/blog/our-candidroot-blog-3/how-to-install-odoo-12-in-ubuntu-18-04-392), I got stumbled upon command:

```
$ sudo adduser --system --quiet --shell=/bin/bash --home=odoo --gecos 'ODOO' --group odoo
[sudo] password for martin: 
adduser: The home dir must be an absolute path.
```

Why is this happening? I'm not well versed into Linux so I'm not sure what to do. I'm trying to look up the error message but couldn't find much.

Comment: `--home=odoo` -> `--home=/home/odoo` (or another suitable path)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ooh the `--home` option is a path? I thought it was a title or name or something. ok let me try.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can replace `--home=odoo` with `--home=/home/odoo`

to clarify according to documentation,

-d, --home HOME_DIR
The new user will be created using HOME_DIR as the value for the user's login directory. The default is to append the LOGIN name to BASE_DIR and use that as the login directory name. The directory HOME_DIR does not have to exist but will not be created if it is missing.

Comment: Is this correct? Because the guy in the comment above said to change it into `--home=/home/odoo` (not `--home-dir`) and I did it and it already works.

Comment: you are absolutely correct; I misspelled the option and have fixed it. Thank you @ChenLiYong